# Multiple jars in classpath not working

Tags: java, command-line, jar, java-6

I have seen several very similar questions on stackoverflow, but haven't come across anything that exactly matches my problem. I have a folder with several .java files, and another folder with two .jar files. I need to include both the jar files while using javac so that the entire project gets compiled at one go:

```
$: javac -classpath .:~/myjardir/*.jar ~/myprojectdir/*.java
```

But if I do this, only the first jar is recognized, and everything that depends on the second jar throws an error. Surprisingly, if I compile each program separately,

```
$: javac -classpath .:~/myjardir/oneofthejars.jar ~/myprojectdir/file1.java
```

then everything works fine. I have also compiled the project separately in Eclipse just to test the code and the jars. It is only when I try to use both the jars with `-classpath` in command line that I get the errors. Wildcard entries are supposed to work in JDK6, so I am at a loss here.

Comment: I would suggest you use a build tool like `ant` or `maven` to keep track of your dependencies and perform your build.  AFAIK using wild cards works for the classpath for the JVM however it might not work for the `javac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [the SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) but here's the relevant paragraph from the Java documentation:

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/** specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The class path wildcards don't work like they do in the Unix shells. The `*` means everything named `*.jar` in the directory. So you don't need to do `*.jar` but just `*`. The following should do what you want:

```
$: javac -classpath .:~/myjardir/* ~/myprojectdir/*.java
```

See [Understanding class path wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) in the [Java SE 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Esp in windows, you need to add double quotes: javac -cp "..\lib\*" test\wc\MyCode.java

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple things in a classpath, you have to separate them by the classpath separator as far as I know.  So ./lib:/lib/mylib would be a valid classpath on a unix system, I think the equivalent would be .\lib;\lib\mylib on a windows system.  You don't have to specify every file, just the directories.